# Save functions in Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, save

I have a new problem, i am using a class named interpreter:

Interpreter.h

```
#ifndef INTERPRETER_H_
#define INTERPRETER_H_

#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Interpreter {
public:
   static Interpreter* getInstance();
   typedef void (*fn)(int, int, int, int);
   static fn opcodes[44];
   static fn functions[43];
private:
   Interpreter() {
      opcodes[9] = addiu;
      opcodes[3] = jal;
      opcodes[8] = addi;
      opcodes[4] = beq;
      opcodes[43] = sw;

      functions[32] = add;
      functions[33] = addu;
      functions[34] = sub;
      functions[18] = mflo;
      functions[26] = div;
      functions[12] = syscall;
      functions[8] = jr;

}
;
void addiu(int, int, int, int);
void addi(int, int, int, int);
void jal(int, int, int, int);
void beq(int, int, int, int);
void sw(int, int, int, int);

void add(int, int, int, int);
void addu(int, int, int, int);
void sub(int, int, int, int);
void mflo(int, int, int, int);
void div(int, int, int, int);
void syscall(int, int, int, int);
void jr(int, int, int, int);


static Interpreter* _instance;
};

 #endif /* INTERPRETER_H_ */
```

Interpreter.cpp

```
#include "Interpreter.h"

Interpreter* Interpreter::_instance = NULL;

Interpreter* Interpreter::getInstance() {
if (_instance == NULL) {
    _instance = new Interpreter();
}
return _instance;
}



 void Interpreter::addiu(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::addi(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::jal(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::beq(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::sw(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }



 void Interpreter::add(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::addu(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::sub(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::mflo(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::div(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::syscall(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }

 void Interpreter::jr(int rs, int rt, int rd, int shamt) {

 }
```

But the program have errors in .h file, exactly in the private constructor Interpreter(), when i try to save the function in array opcodes or functions.

The error is:

cannot convert ‘Interpreter::addiu’ from type ‘void (Interpreter::)(int, int, int, int)’ to type ‘Interpreter::fn {aka void (*)(int, int, int, int)}’

Thanks for help me

Comment: A [mcve] should really be minimal. Please reduce the code you posted to the absolute minimum necessary. (To answer your question: You are declaring arrays of function pointers, but try to assign member function pointers. Those are **very** different beasts.)

Comment: try pointer to member function, means:  `typedef void (Interpreter::*fn)(int, int, int, int);`

Comment: I try that but dont work, this is the error:

`cannot convert ‘Interpreter::addiu’ from type ‘void (Interpreter::)(int, int, int, int)’ to type ‘Interpreter::fn {aka void (Interpreter::*)(int, 
 int, int, int)}’`

Answer (score 0):

You can't point to a non-static member function with a normal function pointer.
You need to use member function pointers:

```
typedef void (Interpreter::*fn)(int, int, int, int);
```